# Scraping a series of links from <a> using BeautifulSoup (in between two other tags)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

Please can you help me to solve a problem in Python based on this html code:

```
<h2 class="sectionTitle">One</h2>
<div><a itemprop="affiliation" href="../../snapshot.asp?carId=1230559">Text1</a></div>
<div><a itemprop="affiliation" href="../../snapshot.asp?carId=1648920">Text2</a></div>
<div><a itemprop="affiliation" href="../../snapshot.asp?carId=1207230">Text3</a></div><div>
<h2 class="sectionTitle">Two</h2>
```

I'm trying to grab the strings (Text1, Text2 ...) as well as the href links in between the two `h2` tags.

Grabbing the strings worked fine by jumping to the `h2` tag (with string="One") and then walking through the siblings until reaching the next `h2` node while grabbing everything on the way.

```
page = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml")

education = []
edu = soup.find("h2", string="One")
for elt in edu.nextSiblingGenerator():
    if elt.name == "h2":
        break
    if hasattr(elt, "text"):
        education.append(elt.text + "\n")
print("".join(education))
```

I can't manage to replicate this in order to collect the links from the `<a>`-tag in an additional list. I was amateurishly going for stuff like education2.append(elt2.get("href")) with very limited success. Any ideas?

Thank you!!

Comment: Could you explain more what criteria a link has to fulfill for you to want to get its text. Can you just get the links by the `itemprop="affiliation"` attribute or does it have to be that they are after the div?

Comment: The itemprop="affiliation" attribute would be ok to identify the links I need!

Comment: Then I would recommend looking up the documentation yourself, it helps with leaning a lot more. If you get stuck just leave a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were pretty close in doing what you want. I made a few changes.

This will give what you want:

```
html = '''<h2 class="sectionTitle">One</h2>
<div><a itemprop="affiliation" href="../../snapshot.asp?carId=1230559">Text1</a></div>
<div><a itemprop="affiliation" href="../../snapshot.asp?carId=1648920">Text2</a></div>
<div><a itemprop="affiliation" href="../../snapshot.asp?carId=1207230">Text3</a></div>
<div>dummy</div>
<h2 class="sectionTitle">Two</h2>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
texts = []
links = []
for tag in soup.find('h2', text='One').find_next_siblings():
    if tag.name == 'h2':
        break
    a = tag.find('a', itemprop='affiliation', href=True, text=True)
    if a:
        texts.append(a.text)
        links.append(a['href'])

print(texts, links, sep='\n')
```

Output:

```
['Text1', 'Text2', 'Text3']
['../../snapshot.asp?carId=1230559', '../../snapshot.asp?carId=1648920', '../../snapshot.asp?carId=1207230']
```

I've added a dummy `<div>` tag with no child tag to show that the code won't fail for any other cases.

---

If the HTML doesn't have any `<a>` tags with `itemprop="affiliation"` apart from the ones you want, you can directly use this:

```
texts = [x.text for x in soup.find_all('a', itemprop='affiliation', text=True)]
links = [x['href'] for x in soup.find_all('a', itemprop='affiliation', href=True)]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
l = """
<h2 class="sectionTitle">One</h2>
<div><a itemprop="affiliation" href="../../snapshot.asp?carId=1230559">Text1</a></div>
<div><a itemprop="affiliation" href="../../snapshot.asp?carId=1648920">Text2</a></div>
<div><a itemprop="affiliation" href="../../snapshot.asp?carId=1207230">Text3</a></div><div>
<h2 class="sectionTitle">Two</h2>
"""
s = soup(l, 'lxml')
final_text = [i.text for i in s.find_all('a')]
```

Output:

```
[u'Text1', u'Text2', u'Text3']
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Unfortunately I have a great many of other `a` tags that I don't want to be scraped which I probably should have added. Also I need the results to be in two separate lists.

Answer (score 2):

Improving @Ajax1234's answer; this will only find  tags with the `itemprop` attribute. See [find_all()](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
l = """
<h2 class="sectionTitle">One</h2>
<div><a itemprop="affiliation" href="../../snapshot.asp?carId=1230559">Text1</a></div>
<div><a itemprop="affiliation" href="../../snapshot.asp?carId=1648920">Text2</a></div>
<div><a itemprop="affiliation" href="../../snapshot.asp?carId=1207230">Text3</a></div><div>
<h2 class="sectionTitle">Two</h2>
"""
s = soup(l, 'lxml')
final_text = [i.text for i in s.find_all("a", attrs={"itemprop": "affiliation"})]
```

Comment: Thanks Oisin, I actually went back to the documentation after you told me to do so and I was pretty helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

My way of solving your problem is as follows:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = '''
<h2 class="sectionTitle">One</h2>
<div><a itemprop="affiliation" href="../../snapshot.asp?carId=1230559">Text1</a></div>
<div><a itemprop="affiliation" href="../../snapshot.asp?carId=1648920">Text2</a></div>
<div><a itemprop="affiliation" href="../../snapshot.asp?carId=1207230">Text3</a></div><div>
<h2 class="sectionTitle">Two</h2>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

# Extract the texts
result1 = [i.text.strip('\n') for i in soup.find_all('div')]
print(result1)

# Extract the HREF links
result2 = [j['href'] for j in soup.find_all('a',href=True)]
print(result2)
```

The list `result1` will output the list of texts enclosed between the `<div>` tags while the list `result2` will output the list of `href links` present inside the `<a>` tags.

**Output:**

```
['Text1', 'Text2', 'Text3', 'Two']
['../../snapshot.asp?carId=1230559', '../../snapshot.asp?carId=1648920', '../../snapshot.asp?carId=1207230']
```

Hope this solution solves the problem!